# gitignore > some ignored files still added to the repository

Tags: gitignore

I don't understand why ignored files are still added to the repository. Are there some circumstances when files which are in the .gitignore list, can be still added to the repository

I added directory to the `.gitignore` before I did anything with the project (project is clean, no trucked or untracked files). Then I built the project. During the build process some files were modified. When the build was done, most of the modified files were ignored, but some were added to the repository. I don't understand this git's selectivity.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, files are added to the index when modified if they were tracked *before* the `.gitignore` referenced them.

Try:

```
git rm --cached -r biz/modules/rest-apis/docs/refAddress
```

Then control that all files are ignored, by selecting one which was added before:

```
git check-ignore -v -- biz/modules/rest-apis/docs/refAddress/GET_1.0_v4_addresses.json
```

You should see a `.gitignore` rule (no output means: the file is not ignored).